# About an UserControl into another Usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface

I have a UserControl that contains other Usercontrols  with many functions in there and sometimes i need to instanciate a UserControl like (Dim x as new usercontrolTest) and this functions are started and i want that functions are started just when i open the UserControl.
Because of this my project is slow to open.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the `DesignMode` property?

Answer (score 0):

The first option would be to move the custom functions from the constructor to the Load event for each child control. In this case, the custom functions would not run until the control was added to the form.

```
Public Sub New()

  ' This call is required by the designer.
  InitializeComponent()

  ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
  'CustomMethod1()  ' Moved this method to the Load event.

End Sub

Private Sub CustomControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  CustomMethod1()
End Sub
```